# Given DAG find smallest DT

Tags: graph-theory

I stumbled upon this graph theory problem, and I think i managed to solve it, but I need some help to making my solution rigorous and some help for prove. I am pretty new to graph theory, so I may use use the language correctly

The problem: 
Given a labelled directed, acyclic and rooted graph $\mathcal{G}$, find a  labelled rooted, directed tree (DT) $\mathcal{D}$, in which multiple vertices may be labelled identically, so that there is a directed edge between two vertices in $\mathcal{D}$, if there is a directed edge in $\mathcal{G}$ with the same two labels, that has as few nodes as possible.

Here rooted means, that is has a node, which can reach all other nodes. And by directed tree i mean a DAG whose underlying undirected graph is a tree.

My solution:

"Cut" the graph, if a node have n>1 entries, then copy it n times, and distribute one entry to each node.

Examples: See picture. I would like to make this procedure more rigorous

Proof: Consider a node, call it N, with n>1 entries. Since we need n paths to N, we need at least n-1 copies of N, making our method optimal. This is very rigorous either. 
[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $\mathcal G$ has $m$ edges; then $\mathcal D$ must also have at least one copy of those $m$ edges. Additionally, when $\mathcal G$ has $s$ source vertices, $\mathcal D$ must contain at least $s-1$ edges that are not in $\mathcal G$: except for one source, which can be the root, $\mathcal D$ should have an edge into each of the other source vertices.

Therefore, $\mathcal D$ must contain at least $m+s-1$ edges. Each non-root vertex of a directed tree has $1$ edge going into it, and the root has $0$, so $\mathcal D$ must contain at least $m+s$ vertices. The procedure below will create a tree with exactly $m+s$ vertices, so it will be optimal.

---

Here is one way we can make your "cut" procedure rigorous:

Go through the vertices in an arbitrary order. When we get to vertex $v$, if there are edges $u_1 v, u_2 v, \dots, u_k v$ pointing into $v$, leave one of them (say, $u_1 v$) alone. Create $k-1$ clones of $v$ (call them $v^{(2)}, \dots, v^{(k)}$ to disambiguate) and replace the edges $u_2v, \dots, u_k v$ with edges $u_2 v^{(2)}, \dots, u_k v^{(k)}$.

All other edges should be left alone until later steps; in particular, the edges out of $v$ should remain edges out of $v$, and the clones $v^{(2)}, \dots, v^{(k)}$ should have no edges leaving them.

As an exception, since we want $\mathcal D$ to be a rooted tree, and therefore connected, we perform one more step in case there are *no* edges into $v$ (that is, if $k=0$). Such nodes are called sources. The first source that we see, we should leave alone; call that vertex $r$ (it will be the root of $\mathcal D$). For each subsequent vertex $v$ that's a source, we should add an edge from $r$ to $v$ in $\mathcal D$. This is not the only way to connect $\mathcal D$, but it is the most straightforward.

If $\mathcal G$ had $s$ source vertices, then there were $s-1$ steps in which we created a new edge of $\mathcal D$, instead of modifying an existing edge of $\mathcal G$. So we have exactly achieved the lower bound of $m+s-1$ edges, and $m+s$ vertices, mentioned at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accept your answer to a rigorous procedure.

I don't understand "When G is connected, G has  edges, then D must also have  edges, and therefore it must have +1 nodes. There's no further room for optimization in the number of nodes." fully. 

How do you conclude, that D only had m+1 nodes. My example 3 has m+2 nodes, so I can't see how this proves, that the "cut" algorithm is optimal. Could you maybe clarify that for me. 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example $3$ has $m+1$ nodes: there are $5$ edges in the original digraph, and $6$ nodes in the resulting tree. (In general, the number of nodes in $D$ will be $m+k$, where $k$ is the number of source vertices in $G$.)

Comment: Ahh I see, I misread edge as node. Can you maybe also explain me, why is obvious, that. "There's no further room for optimization in the number of nodes. I can see it, but i would like to refer to some sentence. 

I will award you the bonus, when I find how to. I appreciate your answer a lot

Comment: I have added more detail to my answer; let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement "such that there is a directed edge between two vertices in D, if there is a directed edge in G with the same two labels" is very strict.

A possible O(n) solution is to run a BFS-like algorithm where for each edge (u,v), we make a copy of v and add it to our tree. However, we keep a mapping of each unique vertex in G to the "designated" vertex in D. This is necessary since there are likely many copies of each vertex floating around and we don't want to expand on all of them. Then we continue the BFS algorithm, but for each vertex v in G, being careful to only add to the corresponding designated vertex in D.